# Erro ao tentar acessar site usando Http Service

Tags: java, aplicação-web, http-request

Olá, pessoas.
Estou precisando seriamente da ajuda de vocês.
Há um sistema no qual estou trabalhando na Universidade que consiste em entrar no sistema acadêmico da universidade, através da requisição de protocolo.
Estou usando as classes da Http Service da Apache, mas apesar de conhecer a eficácia do serviço, não obtive sucesso nesse site específico.

Sei que é possível, porque um conhecido do departamento de computação daqui fez um aplicativo para que os alunos com esse propósito de acessar o sistema e consultar notas, horários, etc.

O processo que eu fiz foi o já mesmo já conhecido de instalar o HTTPFox (ou semelhante) e descobrir os atributos para passar no *BasicNameValuePair*.

Vejam o que estou tentando fazer:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class NavegadorSite {

    public void x () {

        final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                "https://www.sigaa.ufs.br/sigaa/logar.do?dispatch=logOn");
        try {
            final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("width", "1140"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("height", "900"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("urlRedirect", ""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("acao", ""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("acessibilidade", ""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user.login", "unknown"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user.senha", ""));

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            final HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        NavegadorSite ns = new NavegadorSite();
        ns.x();
    }
}
```

Espero que consigam me ajudar, pois preciso muito criar esse robô virtual para acessar o site e capturar algumas informações!

Abaixo está a saída obtida no console do Eclipse. Dos sites testados, apenas esse que gera esse tipo de erro, consolidando assim, uma frustração enorme.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:553)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:412)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at br.ufs.httpcomponents.NavegadorSite.x(NavegadorSite.java:35)
    at br.ufs.httpcomponents.NavegadorSite.main(NavegadorSite.java:50)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
```

Para fechar, só mais uma coisa que acho importante: há algo de ilegal em pegar informações de sites dessa forma?

Para dúvidas complementares estarei aqui para debater.
Desde já agradeço a todos.

Answer (score -1):

Esse Apache Client tem problemas quando acessa sites com *SSL*. No seu caso, o que está causando o problema é exatamente o fato de estar tentando acessar um site seguro (*https*):

```
new HttpPost("https://www.sigaa.ufs.br/sigaa/logar.do?dispatch=logOn");
```

Um bom framework para resolver esse tipo de problema é o [Crawler4j](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j).

Veja [este exemplo](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j#quickstart) de utilização. Nele você consegue capturar exatamente os dados que você precisa do site, e a implementação é extremamente simples.

E o mais importante: funciona bem com sites seguros *HTTPS*.

Comment: Olá, andreycleme. Antes de capturar as informações é necessário fazer login no site, pois o que eu preciso é restrito a cadastrados. O exemplo que você passou não parece tratar desse requisito.

Comment: Murilo, o Crawler4j consegue autenticar sim. Veja esse exemplo na própria documentação:
https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/crawler/authentication/BasicAuthInfo.java